# Drop up menu, with headings vertically centered

Tags: html, css, menu, position

**EDIT: Seeing as two people have misunderstood what i'm going for - i'll make it perfectly clear: I'm looking for a DROP UP menu from a footer, not a DROP DOWN menu from a header.**

This crap has been bugging me for like a week now.
http://jsfiddle.net/pwg24xbf/1/

I need to make the hidden lists as a drop up menu.
I need them to be positioned, percentagewise to the container (BCONT), which means i cannot "position: absolute" and use percentages.

At this point I don't know what to do. Really need help!

In conclusion: What I need is a drop up menu to the list within BCONT. I need ALL sizes, positions and so on in %. NOT IN PX.

Furthermore I need the list VERTICALLY CENTERED within BCONT aswell.

```
<div id="BCONT">
    <ul>
        <li>CHAT<i id="CABUP" class="fa fa-comment"></i></li>
        <li>LANGUAGE<i id="LGBUP" class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
            <ul id="LGBMENU">
                <li>sub1</li>
                <li>sub2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>SERVICES<i id="SVBUP" class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
            <ul id="SVGMENU">
                <li>sub1</li>
                <li>sub2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li style="padding-right:12px;">HELP<i id="HPBUP" class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
            <ul id="HPBMENU">
                <li>sub1</li>
                <li>sub2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

#BCONT {
width: 100%;
height: 4.125%;
background-color: #6779e8;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
font-family:my_fat_font;
overflow: auto;
}
#BCONT ul li {
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 6px;
margin-left: 6px;
padding-right: 6px;
padding-left: 6px;
color:white;
height: 100%;
}
#BCONT ul {
margin: 0px;
height: 100%;
float: right;
vertical-align:middle;
}
#BCONT:after,  {
vertical-align:middle;
}
#BCONT ul li ul {
display: none;
}
#LGBUP, #SVBUP, #HPBUP, #CABUP {
font-size: 20px;
padding-left: 7px;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this via javascript? I don't see any sub menus opening up at all

Comment: First of all, I wanna keep this strictly CSS.
Second, I didn't add the popup features because, I can't seem to get it working and at the same time having the list vertically aligned within the BCONT. I was looking for someone who could finish up this piece of code for me.

Comment: here is an working example, just play with it http://cssdeck.com/labs/another-simple-css3-dropdown-menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best I could do. Sorry if this wasn't what you wanted.

http://jsfiddle.net/pwg24xbf/6/

```
.outerdiv{
        position:relative;
    }
    #BCONT {
        width: 100%;
        height: 7.125%;
        background-color: #6779e8;
        font-family:my_fat_font;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #BCONT .outer-ul>li {
        display: block;
        float:left;
        margin-right: 6px;
        margin-left: 6px;
        padding-right: 6px;
        padding-left: 6px;
        color:white;
        height: 100%;
    }
    #BCONT ul {
        margin: 0px;
        height: 172%;
        float: left;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
    #BCONT:after,  {
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
    #LGBUP, #SVBUP, #HPBUP, #CABUP {
        font-size: 20px;
        padding-left: 7px;
    }
    .inner-ul > li{
        display:block;
    }
    .inner-ul{
        z-index: 9999;
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        background-color:black;
    }
    #LGBMENU,#SVGMENU,#HPBMENU{
        float:none !important;
    }
    .outer-ul>li:hover > .inner-ul{
        display:block;
    }
```

HTML -

```
  <div class="outerdiv">
    <div id="BCONT">
        <ul class="outer-ul">
            <li>CHAT<i id="CABUP" class="fa fa-comment"></i></li>
            <li>LANGUAGE<i id="LGBUP" class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
                <ul class="inner-ul" id="LGBMENU">
                    <li>sub1</li>
                    <li>sub2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>SERVICES<i id="SVBUP" class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
                <ul class="inner-ul" id="SVGMENU">
                    <li>sub1</li>
                    <li>sub2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li style="padding-right:12px;">HELP<i id="HPBUP" class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
                <ul class="inner-ul" id="HPBMENU">
                    <li>sub1</li>
                    <li>sub2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me out!
With that said, this just about how far i've gotten aswell.

Problem is: This code you did makes it a drop DOWN menu from a header element. What I'm trying to create is a drop UP menu from a footer.

Furthermore the submenu's are not taking up the same space as the heading for that submenu.

I don't know, if you kno whow to do this, but again thank you for trying!

Comment: I don't know if you want to have jquery code. But here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pwg24xbf/8/) , I have used jquery to set proper width to inner-ul.

Comment: JQUERY would be acceptable, if there's no way around coding it in pure CSS, i guess.

One problem though: the inner li's are not the same width as the ul within BCONT.

Comment: Wierd.. I see the result in jsf, but when I incorporate the JQ in my issexpress file it just, for some reason, won't work. 

Tried with other JQ scripts, and those are working fine - but your aint! :(

Comment: Could you maybe add the ONLOAD attribute in the JQ code?

Comment: Have jquery script file in head section. And on script section in the head have my code within $(function(){<jq code>}); I suppose that's what you are asking :|

Comment: Well since I'm gonna be using it on several pages ive uncluded the script

$(".inner-ul").each(function() {
        var cur = $(this);
        var width = cur.parent("li").width();
        cur.width(width);
})

as an external file, and attached it in head as follows:
<script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="UI.js"></script>

Still not working for some reason :(

Comment: Furthermore the list is not vertically centered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69862/discussion-between-jason-and-rasmus-hjorth-ludeking).